# How to data bind to a static property on a non-static class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

In my `ViewModel` class I have a static property `AllSupport` but I can't figure out how to bind it correctly. The ListView is already binded to an ObservableCollection `AllEffects` that has the `AllSupport` static property.

I used this:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    Header="GPU">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                Margin="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                IsChecked="{Binding AllSupport[HardwareType].SupportList.IsSupported, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

`AllEffects` is `ObservableCollection` of `EffectViewModel` where it has a static property called `AllSupport` which is of type:
`Dictionary<HardwareType, List<EffectSupport>>` where:

`HardwareType` is an enum, and
`EffectSupport` is an instance class that has a boolean property called `IsSupported`.

I also tried this but then it complains that it can't find `IsSupported` on the `ViewModel` class:

```
IsChecked="{Binding AllSupport[HardwareType].SupportList, Path=IsSupported
```

Any ideas, how to specify this binding?

Comment: Which static property do you want to bind? From your question, I understand that the property that you want to bind is `IsSupported` but from your description it would seem that it is a regular property of the `EffectSupport` class.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I neglected a small detail I think. Will edit but IsSupported is an instance property on a static property in the ViewModel class.

Comment: So currently my code returns a List, how do I specify to get each item inside it in xaml?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `x:Static` whether the class is static or not to access static members.

Untested:

```
IsChecked="{Binding [HardwareType], Source={x:Static prefix:EffectViewModel.AllSupport}}"
```

and you'll need a `prefix` to access your view model's namespace.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So the property on the ViewModel is static but the actual last binding property is an instance. In your example you didn't specify IsSupported, do you know how to use that? Because that's the property on the actual EffectSupport instance obtained from AllSupport[HardwareType].SupportList.

Comment: I just noticed that omission and was looking at it.  Perhaps just change the path to [HardwareType].IsSupported.  Still untested!

Comment: I am still getting the same error where it complains that IsSupported is not a property on a List which is what [HardwareType] returns. I did [HardwareType].IsSupported though because I don't know where else to put the property access.

Comment: So basically this does the same thing as shown in my question, just a different way to access the path. I just don't know how I can make the List of EffectSupport to be binding like ItemsSource does, item by item, not the whole list as a single item.

Comment: Your question was about binding to the static property AllSupport.  Once you have that, it's not a static problem any more.  It's a path problem or some other problem.  To help you with the rest of the problem I need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

This was my scenario:

- Had a non-static class with a static property which was a ObservableCollection
- The class was used as a logger, and to collect specific exceptions from the program

Problem statement:

- How can I bind a non-static class's static member to a List View in XAML

My Solution:

Code behind(Window.cs):

```
public ObservableCollection<T> FooList {get {return    FooLogger.ExceptionList;}}
 //where FooLogger is a non-static class
 //and   ExceptionList is a static ObservableCollection<T>
```

DataContext(Window.cs):

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

XAML(Window.xaml)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FooList}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

Cheers,
v0k